# C#: How to convert data with .db format to .csv while keeping the structure of the data the same?

Tags: winforms, file-conversion

I am creating an application that transfer .db file from a remote server to a local server using SFTP. These files need to be converted to CSV format to later do data visualization.

Each .db has a different name, I want to be able to read each file and convert it to CSV format using C#.
I tried different implementation which was converting to CSV but all the file has the same data.

Below is what I was doing:

```
public DataTable ConverttoDatatable(string path, string tablename)
        {
            SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + path);
            m_dbConnection.Open();
            string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM DADLoggerTable");
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, m_dbConnection);
            DataSet set = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(set);
            DataTable table = set.Tables[0];
            return table;
        }



public void SaveCsv(DataTable dt, string filePath, string tablename)
        {
            FileStream fs = null;
            StreamWriter sw = null;
            try
            {
                fs = new FileStream(filePath + "\\" + tablename + ".csv", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                sw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.Default);
                var data = string.Empty;
                for (var i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    data += dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                    if (i < dt.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        data += ",";
                    }
                }
                sw.WriteLine(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    data = string.Empty;
                    for (var j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        data += dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();
                        if (j < dt.Columns.Count - 1)
                        {
                            data += ",";
                        }
                    }
                    sw.WriteLine(data);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                throw new IOException(ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }
```

These are two method to convert the data, and here how I implemented in C#.

```
foreach (var item_db in files_path)
 {

    var result = item_db.Substring(item_db.Length - 3);
    for (var i = 1; i < files_path.Count() + 1; i++)
        {
            if (result == ".db")
           {

            tablename = string.Format("DADLoggerTable{0}", i);
            DataTable dt = ConverttoDatatable(item_db, tablename);
            SaveCsv(dt, subFolderCSV, tablename);
           }

        }


 }
```

It loop through the db files and it convert file that end with .db
Al the file has the same data, does that mean that it writing the same data to all the files or there is something wrong that I am not aware of.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: You're passing to `ConverttoDatatable` a `tablename` string, but you always query the same table: `"SELECT * FROM DADLoggerTable"`. I assume you want to query `$"SELECT * FROM {tablename}"`. Btw, this: `var result = item_db.Substring(item_db.Length - 3);` is `var result = Path.GetExtension(item_db)`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. True, however, all the table have the same name, it's just the data in them that is different. Thanks for the `GetExtension()`, I will use that. Will it still work if I used  `$"SELECT * FROM {tablename}"`, and pass the table name from every file?

Comment: You're iterating all the tables of each `.db` file. So the tables must have different names. In fact, you're formatting the table names as `DADLoggerTable1`, `DADLoggerTable2`, etc. and pass this name to the method, but then, in the query, you use the same name for all, so you always query the same table in all databases. This: `$"SELECT * FROM {tablename}"` lets you use the table name **you** passed on to perform the query.

Comment: This unless you actually want to query **one** table in **each** database. In this case you don't need the inner loop. You're the only one who knows what's what.

Comment: I am interested in querying one table in each dataset so that I am able to consistently iterate through each file one by one and make sure the whole process is done in one go without doing it manually